# Residue of $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need help finding the residue at the poles. I tried taylor expanding $\cos(z)$ and writing it in exponential form and end up no where. Anyone got hints?

Comment: Do you know the poles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue can be found as

$$ \lim_{z\to \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}} \left( z-\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right)
\frac{1}{\cos(z)} = -\frac{1}{\sin(z)}\bigg|_{z=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}}\,\quad n\in \mathbb{Z} $$

Answer (score 1):

The function $\cos(z)$ has simple zeros at $\pm(2n-1)\pi/2$, so $1/\cos(z)$ has simple poles at these complex numbers.  Now, use [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles) for the residue at simple poles.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll try the series method.

Comment: What do you mean?  And not to complain, because internet points don't matter, but why did you unaccept the first answer to the question, and then accept a later answer that is an exact duplicate?